# Divide csv files to junks base on certain condition using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file which I read through pandas, and I want to divide it to chunks base on the label. I can do this manually using cat and command-prompt, but I have a huge data and I'm thinking of a way to optimize things. Here's how the file looks like:

```
  contactid       label                          sentence
   10012-1af      "ETA"                           "I'm running late"
   35716-iau      "Delay"                         "I am stuck in the traffic"
   13638-oa       "track"                         "Please keep track of the issues at hand."
```

The data goes on like that, and I want to have different csv files with distinct labels such as:

eta.csv:

```
   contactid      label                          sentence
   10012-1af      "ETA"                           "I'm running late"
```

delay.csv:

```
      contactid      label                          sentence
      35716-iau      "Delay"                         "I am stuck in the traffic"
```

My current approach is:

```
    mlr --tsv --from input.csv put -q 'tee > "file_".$label.".csv", $*'

   $ cat file_eta.csv
```

which seems so ineffective because I have to do that manually for every labels I have. Is there any other way to go about this?

Comment: Do you mean **chunks**?

Comment: yeah chunks... hahaha sorry

Comment: So you want one CSV file, with header row, per unique label.

Comment: I want separate files per unique label